# achemso - How to change the author email font style

Tags: fonts, achemso, email

Is it possible to adjust the font sytle of  "E-mail:author@somelab.com" to Time new romans when using achemso? The font style is always CMS S 12.

This is an example document I have.

```
\author{somenone}
\email{somenone@somelab.com}
\affiliation[somelab]{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \rm somelab}
```

The journal needs the whole sentence of email including email address to be in Times new roman style. Is it possible to achieve?

Thanks very much

Comment: Please send me the email you have with this request from the editorial office and \i will raise with my contact at ACS